# Umbraco 13 Macro Parameters Rich Text Editor

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, umbraco-macros

Is there a way to add a rich text editor as a Macro Parameter?

I have tried to add the following package.manifest in the APP_Plugin folder

```
{
    "propertyEditors": [
        {
            "alias": "RichTextMacro",
            "name": "RichTextMacroEditor",
            "isParameterEditor": true,
            "icon": "icon-book-alt-2",
            "editor": {
                "view": "/umbraco/Views/propertyeditors/rte/rte.html",
                "valueType": "TEXT"
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

This half works in that it creates the option to select it in the select editor window of the parameter

[image]

But when you add it to the page, it just appears as a property with no editor:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are being removed in [Umbraco v14](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/pull/15794), hence it is a good idea to look for a different solution other than using Macros.

[image]

Comment: Ah I'm such a fool, I should have just made it as an element type component to add to my block grid!

Comment: Yes, that is a much better option!